# Handling missing images in JQuery

Tags: jquery, image

In JQuery it was previously possible to handle missing images using fn.error()

```
var photo = $('#photo');
photo.find('.photo-wrapper')
    .error(function() { $(this).attr('src' , '/images/nosuchphoto.png'); })
    .attr( 'src', '/images/photoserver/photo.png' );
```

but this has been deprecated in JQuery 1.8.

Now that 1.9 is out, what is the best way to handle missing images?

Answer (score 2):

Use `on("error")` instead.

```
var photo = $('#photo');
photo.find('.photo-wrapper')
    .on('error', function() { $(this).attr('src' , '/images/nosuchphoto.png'); })
    .attr( 'src', '/images/photoserver/photo.png' );
```

Answer (score 0):

For images that might exist i find most elegant solution is useing $ajax, like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your_image.jpg',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "image",
    success: function() {
        /* function if image exists (setting it in div or smthg.)*/
    },
    error: function(){
       /* function if image doesn't exist like hideing div*/
    } 
});
```

But some people like useing hiden images that show themselves after load like:

```
<img src="your_image.jpg" onload="loadImage()">
```

Both solutions are efective, use one that suits your problem best